# Am I wrong about the Monty Hall Problem?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

First off, I don't think its 50/50 always. That's not what this is about.

I know that simulations show that if Monty randomly picks a goat, it IS 50/50. I always thought I understood why this was, but recently I've been looking at discussion boards and the explanation doesn't seem to match mine.

I always thought that if Monty chose a goat randomly, the probability was actually more complicated. It ends up being 50/50, but there are more possible scenarios.

However, I've been seeing lots of explanations that go something like this: "If Monty purposefully reveals a goat that means that he's given you more information, but if he's chosen randomly he tells you nothing." It has me wondering if maybe I've overthought it. Is there actually a more simple explanation for why a randomly revealed goat gives you 50/50?

**By "randomly chooses a goat" I mean that either Monty has no idea what is behind each door or that if he does know he ignores this knowledge in favor of a random choice (ie. coin flip determines which door he opens). Monty only has a choice between the two doors that you have not chosen. Sorry I should have been clearer.

**** Okay let me put it this way. Everyone says that if you choose at random you get no new info. What I don't understand is why this is true. Why does the random reveal not also give you more info? It seems to me that it does..

Comment: What do you find unconvincing about the "no new information" argument as you've quoted it?

Comment: I suggest being more explicit about what you mean by "randomly picks a goat", since the exact strategy used by Monty affects the answer.

Comment: Simpler than the 'no new information' argument? That's hard to do ....

Comment: Edited - sorry should have been more explicit. In terms of the "no new info" argument, doesn't the fact that he opens a door with a goat give you information regardless of his intent? It's just that the info he's given you is different depending on whether he purposefully picked the goat.

Comment: Suppose you have chosen a door. Then you walk to some other door and in complete ignorance you open it. Behind that door you find a goat. Now do you think that your chance on winning a car will change if you choose for another door on base of your discovery? The answer is: no. The discovery does change something, though. Your original chance on winning was $\frac13$. But after the discovery your chance is $\frac12$.

Comment: Except that's not the reason its 50/50. The fact is, you do get more info even if you open the door unintentionally. It's just that the info is different than if the goat has purposefully been revealed.

Comment: Edited again - hopefully a little clearer.

Comment: You begin your question with "First, I don't think it is 50/50 always" . No, of course not. In the original problem, with the original Monty Hall TV program, Monty **does know** behind which doors there is a goat and behind which there is a nice present. That's all the difference of the world and thus you will always have $\;2/3\;$ to win if you change your first choice. Now, assuming Monty does **not** know behind which doors there's a good and he just opens by chance any door, makes the odd 50/50 (it's just the smae to remain with your original door than switching)...

Comment: Can someone explain to me: if you pick a door with a goat, how can Monty "randomly" pick a goat? There is only one door with the goat left, and he needs to pick *that* door.

Comment: @user8734617 I think the idea is that Monty picks randomly and has some chance of revealing the car, but we want to know how to assess the situation in the  case where a goat was revealed.

Comment: @stewbasic What "idea"? The program seemed to make it crystal clear: Monty **always** know what door to open and reveal, of course, a goat behind it...as far as I know, it was never the case he revealed the car.

Comment: @DonAntonio You're describing the classic Monty Hall Problem. I'm describing the variation of the problem that stewbasic explained - Monty reveals the goat after a random guess between the two unchosen doors . I should have been more clear, sorry!

Comment: The situation that I described in my former comment is comparable with the situation in which Monty opens randomly a door that accidently appears to hide a goat. So the situation that @stewbasic describes. I left Monty out on purpose to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Nina "Except that's not the reason its 50/50". The reason that it is 50/50 is simply the fact that the two doors that have not been opened yet have *equal probability* to hide a car.

Comment: @drhab Let’s start from the beginning okay. When most people are faced with the classic Monty Hall problem, they initially guess 50/50, based on the fact that since now there are only two doors, one with a car, one with a goat, that they have an equal chance whether they switch are not. Obviously this isn’t true. My problem is that people always want to claim that this is true in the new situation I’m describing, and I just don’t see how that is. You still get new info when a random door opens and reveals a goat, regardless of who randomly chooses it.

Comment: @drhab Of course they have equal probability to hide a car. But not because you can just ignore the opening of the third door like people who claim 50/50 in the classic Monty Hall problem believe. The explanation you’re giving me sounds like how believe justify their 50/50 claim in the classic problem. I guess I was just hoping someone could explain why the fact that the door was randomly opened let’s you do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is meant by the "no new information" argument. However, here is an argument based on symmetry.

Let $A_i$ denote the event that the car is behind door $i$, and let $O$ denote the collection of events we've observed, including Monty opening door 3 and revealing a goat. If neither you nor Monty know where the car is, the probability of your collective actions can't depend on where the car is. Also in both cases $A_1$ and $A_2$, door 3 will reveal a goat. Thus
$$
  P(O|A_1)=P(O|A_2).
$$
Suppose that the car placement is uniformly random, so $P(A_1)=P(A_2)$. Now applying Bayes' theorem,
$$
  P(A_1|O)=P(A_2|O).
$$
More generally, this argument shows that no matter how elaborate the game is, the closed doors are all equally likely to have the car provided:

- The car placement is uniformly random,
- No participant in the game knows its location,
- Only goats have been revealed.

To illustrate with an example, suppose we arrange the probabilities in a table with a column for each car position, and a row for each possible sequence of observations. After we make some observations, to determine the probability of the car being behind each door, we should find the appropriate row in the table and compute the relative probabilities in that row (that is, divide each probability in the row by the sum of the row).

To make it clear that it doesn't matter how you and Monty play, suppose we have a biased coin with head probability $3/5$. First you flip and pick door 1 on heads and door 2 on tails. Then Monty flips and selects the leftmost free door on heads. The initial probabilities are
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  \text{Observations}&\text{Car behind }1&\text{Car behind }2&\text{Car behind }3\\ \hline
  &1/3&1/3&1/3
\end{array}$$
After the first flip:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  \text{Observations}&\text{Car behind }1&\text{Car behind }2&\text{Car behind }3\\ \hline
  H\,(\text{You pick }1)&3/15&3/15&3/15\\
  T\,(\text{You pick }2)&2/15&2/15&2/15
\end{array}$$
After the second flip:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  \text{Observations}&1&2&3\\ \hline
  HH\,(\text{You pick }1\text{, Monty picks }2)&9/75&9/75&9/75\\
  HT\,(\text{You pick }1\text{, Monty picks }3)&6/75&6/75&6/75\\
  TH\,(\text{You pick }2\text{, Monty picks }1)&6/75&6/75&6/75\\
  TT\,(\text{You pick }2\text{, Monty picks }3)&4/75&4/75&4/75
\end{array}$$
In each row, all three entries are equal; they must be because the process so far has been independent from where the car actually is. Finally we find out what's behind Monty's door:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  \text{Observations}&1&2&3\\ \hline
  HH;\,\text{Pick 1, open 2, reveal goat}&9/75&0&9/75\\
  HH;\,\text{Pick 1, open 2, reveal car}&0&9/75&0\\
  HT;\,\text{Pick 1, open 3, reveal goat}&6/75&6/75&0\\
  HT;\,\text{Pick 1, open 3, reveal car}&0&0&6/75\\
  TH;\,\text{Pick 2, open 1, reveal goat}&0&6/75&6/75\\
  TH;\,\text{Pick 2, open 1, reveal car}&6/75&0&0\\
  TT;\,\text{Pick 2, open 3, reveal goat}&4/75&4/75&0\\
  TT;\,\text{Pick 2, open 3, reveal car}&0&0&4/75
\end{array}$$
Now we do get some information; if we find a goat behind Monty's door, the car definitely isn't there. However if a goat is revealed, the probabilities behind the other two doors are still equal; they are the same as in the previous table. Thus the car is equally likely to be behind either closed door.

Comment: btw if you prefer tables to probability notation, you can interpret an event $E$ as a set of table cells, $P(E)$ as the sum of probabilities in those cells, and $P(E|F)=P(E\cap F)/P(F)$ as the fraction within $F$ of probability that also lies in $E$.

Comment: I have the feeling that this is the answer I'm looking for and yet I am completely unable to understand it due to lack of probability training. (100% my fault 0% yours)

Comment: @Nina I added an example with probability tables, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you!! def more clear what you're doing now! only question - in this situation, you never consider what happens if the contestant originally chooses door 3, why doesn't that have to be considered? i understand that with the parameters you have laid out, it will never happen, but is it fair to lay out parameters where this is the case? doesn't that take away from the random variable? thanks!!

Comment: @Nina I picked an example where you never pick door 3, just to keep the tables small. Hopefully it's clear that the conclusion (two nonzero entries are equal in all goat rows) will hold no matter what method you and Monty use to make the choices (as long as they are independent from the actual car location).

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain this to me. i have a couple of hesitations, and I'm not sure if they're legitimate complaints or just me not understanding probability. 1. I don't understand how these charts can be compared with the monty hall problem. it isn't the same thing, for instance in your final chart, you pick the car just as often as you pick the goat. this fundamentally changes the problem. 2. if I'm understanding these charts right, the probability in each square is the chances that the column title and row title are both true, right? (cont.)

Comment: this doesn't make sense in regards to the last table though. how is there a 9/75 chance that both the car is behind door 2 and you've opened door 2 to find a car?? the only caveat i can see is whether you originally picked door 1 or 3, except in your version you can't even pick door 3 first. it just seems like a paradox to me?

Comment: @Nina I don't understand question 1; do you mean you'd prefer to see the situation where Monty chooses between the closed doors with equal probability? Re 2: Yes your understanding is right. Here "find car" means that the door opened by Monty reveals a car. I'm only considering the game up to that point, ie not including the player possibly switching and possibly getting a prize (Maybe you took "find car" to mean the player wins the car? Sorry for the ambiguity).

Comment: So cell (2,2), for example, gives the probability that the car is behind door 2 ($1/3$) and you pick door 1 ($3/5$) and Monty picks door 2 ($3/5$) and Monty reveals a car (which is certain given the previous points); the final probability is $1/3\times 3/5\times 3/5=9/75$.

Comment: For question 1: I guess I just don't understand why you've set up these arbitrary rules instead of leaving both you and Monty's choice completely random. Even if it doesn't change the result, I find it very confusing. I'm not so worried about this anymore, because I actually set up the same charts assuming both you and Monty's choice were totally random. It was all making sense to me as I replicated your first three charts, but when I got to the fourth, I definitely hit a wall. I don't understand how you assigned the probabilities there.

Comment: Isn't that circular? You're right, in the cell (2,2) scenario, Monty is certainly going to reveal a car. You're saying: "What are the chances that the car is behind door 2, you've originally picked door 1, Monty picks door 2, and door 2 has a car?" Right? Wouldn't that be 100%?

Comment: You originally have a 1/3 chance of choosing a car. This is true. But you can't then add the fact that a car was found in a certain place to your probability calculations? Take the most basic example. Three doors, one car, random choice. By your logic, you can combine the fact that each door has a 1/3 chance of having the car and you have a 1/3 chance of finding the car to get a 1/9 chance of choosing the car.

Comment: If we assume "car is behind 2 and Monty opens 2", then the probability of revealing a car is 100%. This is known as a conditional probability. But the cell value is the probability that "car is behind 2 and Monty opens 2 and reveal car and..." - it includes the probabilities of the previous events. Note that in each table, the sum of all the cell values is 1.

Comment: I'm retracting my immediately previous comment. I don't think it's exactly analogous to what you're doing, and I now see that it's very likely that you will think my complaint is with table 2, which it is not. Let me try it like this. With each table, you're adding another factor that reduces the odds. Up till table 3, this makes perfect sense to me. From table 3, there is a 9/75 chance of the following things happening. You choose #1, Monty chooses #2, car is behind #1. Then you add another factor: whether or not you reveal a car. cont.

Comment: But this revelation does not tell you anything! In 100% of cases you are now going to reveal a car, because you've already assumed that.

Comment: :/ previous two comments refer to Monty's choice of car, not mine.

Comment: One way to interpret each table is: If we played the game 75 times, how many times would we expect to end up in each cell? Cell (1,2) of table 4 (car behind 2, you pick 1, Monty opens 2, reveals goat) is impossible, so that cell is 0. We expect 9 trials to go in (1,2) of table 3 (Car behind 2, you pick 1, Monty picks 2) (I think you agree here?). Those same 9 trials will go in cell (2,2) of table 4 (Car behind 2, you pick 1, Monty opens 2, reveals car).

Comment: I see now. My mistake was assuming that table 4 was a progression, when it fact you were just dividing table 3 based on what we already know. If only we could make 3D tables...

Comment: @Nina Note that all 4 tables are interpreted the same way - the process for deriving one table from the next is still the same. eg the $1/3$ from table 1 cell (1,1) (car behind 1) gets split between table 2 cells (1,1) (car behind 1, H) and (2,1) (car behind 1, T) in the ratio 3:2. Similarly table 3 cell (1,2) gets split between table 4 cells (1,2) and (2,2) - but it all goes into cell (2,2) because, as you say, Monty will certainly reveal a car.

Comment: You're right.. I guess I have to admit what no one wants to ... I didn't make a mistake, I just didn't understand. Anyway thank you so much for taking the time to walk me through this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_i$ be: you pick door $i$

Let $C_i$ be: door $i$ has the car

Let $E_i$ be: Monty shows a goat behind door $i$

Let’s go with: you pick door $1$ and Monty shows a goat behind door $2$. Now what?

Well, let's assume Monty always makes a random choice when opening one of the two remaining doors (maybe because Monty doesn't know where the prize is, or because he always just flips a coin to determine which one to open, or ....). 
That is, after you picking door $1$, he could just as well have opened up door $3$, and indeed in this scenario it is possible that Monty sometimes does end up opening a door that has the car.

Thus, we have:

$$P(E2|C1,P1) = P(E2|C3,P1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Notice that of course we do have that

$$P(E2|C2,P1) = 0$$

since the event of Monty opening up door 2 as having a goat is impossible if it has a car!

OK, so this gives us:

$$P(E2|P1) = P(E2|P1,C1)\cdot P(C1) + P(E2|P1,C2)\cdot P(C2) + P(E2|P1,C3)\cdot P(C3) =$$

$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$

And therefore:

$$P(C3 | E2 , P1) = \frac{P(E2|C3 , P1) \cdot P(C3|P1)}{P(E2|P1)}=$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{3}}{ \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Now, compare this with the situation that Monty does *not* always pick randomly one of the remaining doors, but will always choose the one that has the goat if one of the remaining two has the car (of course, if both remaining doors have a goat, we'll assume that Monty does pick randomly one of those two).

OK, so now we still have:

$$P(E2|C1,P1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

and of course we also still have:

$$P(E2|C2,P1) = 0$$

but we get a different value for:

$$P(E2|C3,P1)=1$$

For now Monty is *sure* to open door $2$ when you pick $1$ and the car is behind $3$.

So this changes the value of:

$$P(E2|P1) = P(E2|P1,C1)\cdot P(C1) + P(E2|P1,C2)\cdot P(C2) + P(E2|P1,C3)\cdot P(C3) =$$

$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$$

And therefore of:

$$P(C3 | E2 , P1) = \frac{P(E2|C3 , P1) \cdot P(C3|P1)}{P(E2|P1)}=$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{3}}{ \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

So, there you go: Monty's intent makes all the difference: if the opening of the door with the goat was the result of him always just randomly picking one of the remaining doors, then switching does not matter, but if he will make sure never to show the car, then switching does matter!

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm not great at reading probability notation. (I always use tables.) I think, however, that this is the explanation I have been using in the past. I'm wondering if there is a way to explain that's easier than the original problem, because the reasoning I always see is that "two outcomes, hence 50/50" works when the door is opened randomly. It is 50/50, but its not because there are only two outcomes..I think? Thank you so much for this answer!!

Comment: @Nina I agree ... "two outcomes hence 50/50" is of course bad reasoning!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have picked door $1$. If Monty picks the door at random, there are the following possibilities:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}\text{Car behind}&\text{Monty picks}&\text{You win}&\text{Probability}\\\hline 1&2&Yes&1/6\\1&3&Yes&1/6\\2&2&No&1/6\\2&3&No&1/6\\3&2&No&1/6\\3&3&No&1/6\end{array}$$

So, in the rows $1,2,4,5$ where Monty has revealed a goat (probability $4/6$), rows $1,2$ (probability: $1/3$) give you the victory if you don't switch (conditional probability: $\frac{1/3}{2/3}=\frac{1}{2}$).

If Monty picks the door with a goat on purpose, then there are the following possibilities:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}\text{Car behind}&\text{Monty picks}&\text{You win}&\text{Probability}\\\hline 1&2&Yes&1/6\\1&3&Yes&1/6\\2&3&No&1/3\\3&2&No&1/3\end{array}$$

and the probability that you win with no switching (rows $1,2$) is $1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary question seems to be: is there a simple explanation of why the probability you have chosen the car is $\frac12$ if Monty chooses randomly and reveals a goat?

What counts as a simple explanation is partly a personal thing, but here is an argument - or perhaps we should call it a thought experiment - which for me captures the intuitive reason it is $\frac12$:

Suppose your friend holds out a standard deck of $52$ cards, face down. You choose one at random and take it but don't reveal it. Your friend then accidentally drops one of the remaining 51 cards. It falls to the floor and you see that it is a club. What is the probability that you now hold a spade?

Well, the $51$ cards that have not been revealed are *all equally likely* to be yours, since there is no reason that any of them should have different likelihoods of being yours than any other. Therefore since $13$ of those are spades the probability that your hold a spade is $\frac{13}{51}$.

The Monty Hall problem where Monty chooses at random and reveals a goat is exactly analogous. Out of the remaining two doors, one is a car and so the probability you have chosen a car is $\frac12$.

The question naturally arises: if Monty deliberately chooses a goat, how does this change things?

In my cards analogy, this corresponds to the situation where your friend deliberately chooses a club and drops it on the floor. In this case, the $51$ unrevealed cards are *not* all equally likely to be yours; the $12$ unrevealed clubs are slightly more likely to be yours than the others, since their having escaped the deliberate club-dropping constitutes some (weak) evidence that they were "hiding" in your hand!

If we want to know the probability that you now hold a spade in this case, we can argue as follows: before the club was dropped, the probability that you held a spade was $\frac{13}{52}$ = $\frac14$. Now the revealing of the club gives you no new information about probability of your having originally chosen a spade, since we knew all along that a club would be revealed no matter what. Therefore the probability you hold a spade is still $\frac14$.

Analogously in the Monty Hall problem, the probability you originally chose the car is $\frac13$, and if Monty deliberately reveals a goat that gives you no new information about the probability that you originally chose a car (since we knew all along that a goat would be revealed whatever), and that probability remains $\frac13$.

I speculate, since there was come confusion about it above, that the "no new information" argument actually refers to this, i.e. it is when Monty chooses a goat deliberately that we get "no new information", *not* when he does so at random.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite getting the card analogy. It seems much more complicated than Monty Hall

Comment: I'm confused about the situation that corresponds to the classic Monty Hall Problem. Your second paragraph seems to contradict the first. The second paragraph seems right to me, but I don't understand why the first is necessary to reach that conclusion. In the first you claim that a deliberate club revelation means it's more likely that you picked a club. If your friend will always reveal a club, you've learned nothing about the card in your hand. You still have a 1/4 chance of having chosen a club, as you explain in paragraph #2.

Comment: In the random drop scenario, the random revelation of a card does tell you something: you're more likely to have originally picked a non-club. Additionally, this scenario is not directly analogous to the random choice variation of Monty Hall. It's much more complicated.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the paragraphs beginning "In my cards analogy..." and "If we want to know..." You're right, the first paragraph is not necessary for the second. They are independent arguments serving different purposes. The first is an explanation of why the earlier argument leading to a probability of 13/51 for the random-drop scenario _no longer works_ in the deliberate-club-drop scenario, since the 51 remaining cards are no-longer "equivalent" in a sense. The second finds the probability in the deliberate-club-drop scenario.

Comment: I agree that in the random-drop scenario, the revelation of a card tells you something. I disagree that my scenario is not analogous to Monty Hall: if you imagine my scenario but where a deck of cards consists of 2 goats and 1 car, instead of 13 clubs, 13 diamonds, 13 hearts and 13 spades, then I think it replicates Monty Hall. It is of course more complicated in terms of having bigger numbers, but somehow that helps me to think about it more clearly, by getting away from small numbers like 1 and 2... perhaps that's a peculiarity of me!

Comment: It's more complicated because you don't originally have a 1/52 chance of picking a spade and because you've only revealed one card, not every card but the chosen card and one other. I'm going to spend some time thinking about your version though! Considering more complex examples just increases your understanding. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I've been seeing lots of explanations that go something like this: "If Monty purposefully reveals a goat that means that he's given you more information, but if he's chosen randomly he tells you nothing." It has me wondering if maybe I've overthought it. Is there actually a more simple explanation for why a randomly revealed goat gives you 50/50?

That is backwards.

- By cheating, Monty denies information.   Monty the Cheater was certain to have revealed a goat, so revealing a goat tells you nothing more than that.   There was $1/3$ probabilty that you picked the car, and that remains so after revealing one of the goats.
- On the other hand, Monty the fair had $1/3$ probability of revealing a car, and so revealing the goat tells you the condition of the world.   You are among the possible worlds where Monty didn't reveal the car: Bayes' Rule revises the (conditional)probability for you picking a car to $(1/3)\div(2/3)$.   That is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already presented versions of the "more complicated" explanation. It is, in my opinion, the better way to approach the problem: it does a better job avoiding the possibility of intuition leading you astray. Nevertheless, I'm posting a defense of the "no new information" argument because I think it is sound if presented carefully.

As you noted, you can't just say there is no new information -- obviously you get new information when the door opens. Beforehand there was a possibility that the car was behind the opened door, now there is not.

To make the argument sound, we have to present some version of the following. Suppose the door opened was door #3. Originally, the car is equally likely to be behind door #1 and behind door #2. Now two things happen: door #3 is *chosen by Monty*, and door #3 is *opened*. Since the random process by which door #3 is chosen *does not depend on the location of the car*, the *choosing* of door #3 does not give any new information about the location of the car. The *opening* of door #3 (and revelation of a goat) doesn't give any new information about the *relative probability* of the car being behind door #1 vs. door #2. So overall you get no new information about the relative probability, and they remain equally likely -- 50/50.

This is in contrast with classic Monty Hall, where the *opening* doesn't give any new information about the relative probability, but the *choosing* does, since the choosing process is different depending on whether the car is behind the door the contestant originally picked (in which case the choice is random between the two other doors) vs. whether the car was behind the other door (in which case the choice is determined).

Is this "simpler" than the other explanations posted? It involves less drawing out charts, but more careful thought and avoiding pitfalls. So it's up to you to decide.

Comment: TL;DR: The "no new information" argument works if it means Monty's _choice_ of door gave no new information, in contrast to classic Monty Hall. The _opening_ of the door gives information but doesn't affect the equal likelihood.

Comment: The opening of door #3 to reveal a goat does depend on the location of the car. It's more likely to happen if you've originally chosen the car. Sorry if I'm missing something

Comment: @Nina It is true that door #3 revealing a goat is more likely to happen if the car is not behind door #3 (100% chance) vs. if the car is behind door #3 (0% chance). But the fact that there is a goat behind door #3 does not give any new information as to whether the car is behind door #1 vs. door #2, so they remain equally likely.

Comment: @Nina The important point here is to focus on the relative probability of door #1 vs. door #2. We get new information about door #3, and therefore about the relative probabilities of #1 vs. #3 and #2 vs. #3 (and #1 vs. #2-3 combined, etc.), but we get no new information about the relative probability #1 vs. #2.

Comment: The problem relies on a guess prior to the revelation of the goat. If you don't guess, then door #3 gives you no info. But it's not the Monty Hall problem if you don't guess. (also - i can add "the revelation of the goat" to the things i never thought I'd say list lol)

Comment: @Nina lol indeed. You raise a good point about the guess, but I still think the argument goes through. After you guess, we can renumber the doors so the door you guessed is called door #1. The relatively likelihood of door #1 vs. door #2 is still equally likely after the guess. Then proceed as I argued.

Comment: I think we might be going in circles here. We both agree that with a random guess revealing goat it's 50/50. This becomes obvious when you examine all the information given by revelation of said goat. 2/4 times you pick the car 2/4 you don't, which is of course 50/50. But I'm looking for an explanation that does not require 4 scenarios. Essentially can you prove that if a goat revelation is random, then all the people who originally guessed 50/50 were right and essentially you have the problem that people originally assumed: 2 equally likely outcomes, hence 50/50

Comment: as i type that comment its becoming obvious to me that the answer is no. i was just thrown off because the fact that Monty intentionally opens goat door in classic example is often cited as the reason that you can't just eliminate door #3 and pretend it never existed, when in reality you can never do that. it just so happens that if the choice is random its the intuitive 50/50 choice

Comment: @Nina I really like your question, and I'm still not sure. To show that it's 50/50 by my argument, you have to go through a bunch of factors and show that none affect equal likelihood: the guess, the choosing of the door, the revelation of the goat. I think that's a qualitatively different (but probably not "simpler") argument from drawing out the 4 scenarios.

Comment: @Nina Put differently: I disagree with your last comment. In **both** problems, when you find out door #3 contains a goat, you _can_ eliminate door #3 and pretend it never existed. The critical moment comes when Monty _chooses_ door #3. In classic Monty Hall, the _choice_ of door #3 adjusts your probabilities to 1/3-2/3 even before Monty opens the door! In your version of the problem, it is clear that the _choice_ of the door gives no new information and is thus completely irrelevant. The subsequent _opening_ is relevant, and you eliminate door #3 and pretend it never existed.

Comment: We are only considering scenarios in which he opens a goat door, correct? In the random choice version, I could make the argument that the probability changes as soon as Monty chooses the door. Just the fact that his random choice happens to be a goat makes it more likely that my original choice was the car. This happens before the door is opened.

Comment: @Nina We don't know yet that it's a goat door. At that point the probability is still even for all 3. Once he opens it,  one of two things happen: it's a car and the probability is 1 that the car is there, or it's a goat and the probability is even between the other two

Comment: @Nina So knowledge that it's a goat door is part of the opening phase,  not the choosing phase

Comment: we do know that it's a goat door - it's stated in the problem. if we see monty randomly point to one of the two doors without the info that he's choosing a goat then you're right. but he has chosen a goat. i know this sounds like cheating, but its correct. the fact that we don't consider the situations where the car is chosen doesn't change the advantage that knowing he picks a goat gives us

Comment: i'm thinking that you're not going to believe my last point, so imma try to explain it a little better. I think your assumption is that the only info Monty's random choice can give us is whether or not a certain door has a goat. if you believe that, then i can see how the fact that his random choice might turn out to be a car casts some doubt on that. but that is not the only thing we learn - we also now know that the original door has a higher chance of concealing a car. just because sometimes Monty will pick a car door doesn't mean that this isn't true every time he picks a goat door

Comment: @Nina I'm not sure I understand you, so let me confirm one thing.  My understanding of the problem is: "A car and two goats are randomly placed behind 3 doors. You guess 1, and Monty randomly chooses one of the other 2. Monty opens that door and reveals a goat. What is the probability your guessed door hides a car?" In this statement it's clear that the knowledge it's a goat door comes at the _opening_ stage and not before. Did I misstate the problem?

Comment: That’s a valid way to state the problem. Notice that we’re only considering situations were the goat is revealed. We see that it is a goat when Monty opens it, but the goat is behind the door even before he opens it, right? The second he chooses that door, whether he points to it or just decides in his mind that he’s going with that one, the probabilities change. Because it’s a goat. He’s chosen a goat. In every case we’re considering, there is a goat behind that door. The fact that no one in the game knows it’s a goat does not change the fact that it’s a goat.

Comment: @Nina It seems to me you are claiming we can take knowledge that we don't yet know into account when computing the changing probability throughout the game.  If that's your argument, I disagree. Consider a new problem: the same story, but after Monty reveals the goat, he also opens the door you guessed to reveal a car (yay!). Will you now say that since, in every case we're considering,  the car was behind the door you guessed the whole time, the probability that the car was behind that door became $1$ when you guessed it?

Comment: “In classic Monty Hall, the choice of door #3 adjusts your probabilities to 1/3-2/3 before Monty even opens the door!” This is your claim. It is true. But it is not because you know Monty will pick a goat. Before he opens door #3, you don’t know which door he has chosen. You have learned nothing. The probabilities have changed, but you can’t apply this info until the door opens. I’m claiming the same thing.  The random choice of a goat changes the probability. Obviously, the contestant/you cannot apply this info until the door opens.

Comment: I’m not claiming that you gain info before the door opens. I’m claiming the probability changes before the door is opened. Which you have also claimed.

Comment: Regarding your hypothetical, yes, the probability changes when she picks a door. In all cases where the original choice is correct, the original choice will be correct. I’m not claiming the contestant knows this. When I say “In all cases we’re considering, Monty will randomly pick a goat,” I’m not saying “ The contestant is aware that Monty will always pick a goat.”

Comment: @Nina Perhaps I was imprecise.  I will try to be more precise.  My claim is that upon Monty's choosing which door to open and the contestant (or an onlooker) learning that information, and assuming that contestant knows how Monty makes the choice, the probability in the eyes of the contestant changes before the door opens.

Comment: @Nina I fear we've been talking about different probabilities.  Perhaps we should both be more precise.  I'd like to understand what you mean by probability.  To me, it seems that in any case, there is a fact of the matter where the car is before the game begins, so according to your last comment the probability should always be 1-0-0. How can you ever talk about it being 1/2-1/2 or 1/3-2/3?

Comment: Your hypothetical was not that we are only considering cases where a car exists. It was that we are only considering cases in which the contestant chooses a car. In every single one of these cases, the original choice will be the car, because that's all we are considering. The difference between this and only considering cases where he reveals a goat is that your hypothetical leaves nothing left to solve.

Comment: I'm sorry I misinterpreted your claim. If you know which door Monty will open and that he will always reveal a goat then him pointing to the door is essentially him opening the door to reveal a goat. I was confused because I don't see how this has anything to do with my original question. Perhaps we should back up to that point and start again?

Comment: @Nina Actually I'm going to revamp the argument, if that's okay with you. To make sure we're on the same page, we'll always be asking about the probability of an outcome given a certain information set (so I'll try to avoid using language about probability changing, since the information set is fixed). You can interpret this in a frequentist manner as referring to the set of all cases in which that information holds true, which seems to be your preference from the last few comments.

Comment: @Nina Let's call the two problems CMH (for classic Monty Hall) and RMH (for random-choice Monty Hall). In both problems we're asked for the probability that the car is behind door #1, given three pieces of information: (A) The contestant guessed Door #1. (B) Monty chose to open door #3. (C) There is a goat behind Door #3.

Comment: @Nina Let's deal with CMH first. In CMH, it is true that (B) entails (C), but not the reverse -- there are cases (not under consideration in our problem) in which there is goat behind Door #3, but Monty chose to open a different door. So (B) actually gives us more information than (C) (i.e., (B) limits the scope of the cases under consideration more than (C) does). It turns out that (B) is the crucial piece of information which makes Door #1 less likely to hide the car than Door #2. (C) doesn't affect the equal likelihood of Door #1 vs. Door #2 (by a symmetry argument), but (B) does.

Comment: @Nina In RMH, on the other hand, (B) doesn't give us any "relevant" information. The argument for RMH being 50-50 is that none of the three pieces of information impacts the equal likelihood of Door #1 vs. Door #2: (A) clearly does not, (B) does not because the choice is made randomly and not based on the location of the car, and (C) does not just as (C) does not in the CMH problem.

Comment: Thank you for the revamp and also the notation. Makes this a lot easier! I think actually though that your explanation is a little backwards. In CMH, it's true that there are cases where there is a goat behind door #3 and Monty chooses to open another door, but in all cases he reveals a goat. We are considering all of these cases. Constraining the problem by door (ie. "Monty opens door #3") is not the same as constraining by outcome (ie. "Monty always chooses a goat, random or deliberate.") The first is done for convenience. It makes it easier to discuss, as we are doing now. (cont)

Comment: The second is done because it changes the problem. (B) actually gives us no information about door #1. Neither does (C). They give us information about door #2, however. Now lets look at RMH. In this situation (B) does give us information about door #1. Door #1 is more likely to conceal the goat! This effect is canceled out, for lack of a better term, by the new info we have learned about door #2 in both cases. (cont.)

Comment: Clarification: "Door #1 is more likely to conceal the *car*!" (not goat)

Comment: I'm actually done sorry, disregard "(cont.)"

Comment: @Nina How does (B) give us that?

Comment: If your original choice was a goat, Monty would only have a 50% chance of revealing a goat. If it was a car, he has a 100% chance. Monty randomly pointing to a door that conceals a goat is more likely if you've chosen the car.

Comment: @Nina (B) makes does not include that the door opened concealed a goat. Anything you learn from that has to come from (C)

Comment: You don't learn anything till (C). But the probabilities change at (B). Even if they did change at (C), your argument was that neither (A), (B), or (C), affect the probability.

Comment: @Nina I don't want to talk about probability changing.  The only piece of information given in the problem that affects the probability is (C) - if you had just (A) and (B), the probabilities would all be 1/3 still.  (C) does affect the probability, but not the relative probability of door #1 vs door #2.

Comment: I don’t see how we can just suspend discussion about probability changes, because that’s what your original point was all about. I’ll try though. In CMH, (A) is a huge deal. It’s the reason the answer is what it is. (B) and (C) (which in CMH are the same thing) are almost irrelevant in comparison. They only tell you what door you should switch to. They don’t give you any info on why you should switch. That’s all (A). In RMH, (A) is still a big deal, but the combo of (B) and (C) also tell you a lot about whether or not you should switch. This is the “complicated” explanation.

Comment: I’m looking for a more simple explanation. Most likely that for some reason in RMH, (A) is not actually a big deal. At this point, I’m almost 100% sure there isn’t one.

Comment: @Nina please explain where you are coming from on CMH. to me, in CMH, (A) is irrelevant, and (B) is the crux

Comment: (A) is the fact that the contestant guessed door #1, yes? Assuming this choice was random, they had a 1/3 chance of being right. In CMH, the reason that you should switch is that you’ll win if your original guess was wrong and you’ll lose if it was right. As I explain this I’m thinking that the reason you should switch is not so much (A) as it is a piece of info we have not considered: your original guess is most likely wrong. *This* is the reason you should switch. This is true regardless of which door Monty purposefully opens. (B) and (C) only tell you which door to switch to.

Comment: @Nina Ah -- what I mean by the crux is as follows. If you changed the problem by eliminating some information, what would happen? If you had only information (A), then of course you still know nothing; the probabilities are still 1/3-1/3-1/3. By the rules of Monty Hall you can't have (B) happen without (A) (Monty need to know the guess in order to determine how to choose which door to open), so I suppose it's some combination of (A) and (B) which gives 1/3-2/3-0; but (A) alone just gives 1/3-1/3-1/3. (C) alone, or (C) with (A), gives 1/2-1/2-0.

Comment: @Nina In RMH, the point is that eliminating (B) never does anything, since (B) was just a random choice. Also (B) no longer depends on (A), so we can similarly eliminate (A) without doing anything. So (A+B+C) has the same probability as (C) alone, which is 1/2-1/2-0.

Comment: @Nina Incidentally, the way I'm using "information," I wouldn't consider "Your original guess is most likely wrong" as "information" -- that's a probabilistic deduction that can be made based on the information at hand, not something we would state in the problem. "Information" as I'm using it is facts on the ground that change the problem and narrow the scope of cases considered.

Comment: @Nina This formulation is perhaps a less mathematically-worded version of stewbasic's answer.

Comment: I’m not sure that this discussion is benefiting me anymore. stewbasic’s explanation pointed to the fact that when considering all scenarios, Monty has a 1/3 chance of choosing a car. We are not considering cases where Monty chooses a car. Therefore we are not considering 1/3 of the original cases. The contestant has a 1/3 chance of choosing a car and 1/3 of scenarios have been eliminated. The chance that they haven’t chosen a car is now 1/3. 50/50. I don’t see how this relates to what you’re saying? In RMH, you cannot disregard (A) because you don’t know (B).

Comment: @Nina I'm sorry, I can't seem to find where I'm not getting across to you -- always a danger in internet communication. My fault, I'm sure. I'm also finding it difficult to understand your recent objections. I don't know what you mean by "you don't know (B)" -- (B) is a piece of information given in the statement of the problem. By "disregard (A)" I mean "the probability of a different problem in which information (A) is not given is the same as the probability of this problem" -- perhaps this was not coming across?

Comment: I see what happened with (B). During the course of this discussion, I forgot it’s original meaning and assumed it meant that Monty intentionally chooses a goat. So when I said “when we don’t know (B),” what I meant was “when we know (B) was random.” And it’s true what you said about (A): in this situation, the correct answer is the one you would get if you just eliminated (A). But that isn’t a reason for why you can eliminate (A). This is overly simplistic, but “2+2=4 because 4 is my favorite number” isn’t correct. Just because you got the right answer doesn’t mean you understand.

Comment: @Nina Of course that's true -- you can't just disregard (A) for no reason. The reason you can disregard (A) is that it's a random choice that is made the same way no matter where the car is, so it cannot give any information about where the car is. Perhaps this is the hidden premise you are uncomfortable with: "If a piece of information is generated in such a way that does not depend on the original setup, the probability will be the same whether that piece of information is given or not." Do you accept that premise?

Comment: If you can disregard (A) because you don’t know where the car is when you’ve made the choice, why can’t you disregard it in CMH? I’m afraid I don’t quite understand that premise. Perhaps this is the problem. As I’m understanding it, it relates to your first claim like this: the fact that your original choice has a 1/3 probability of being a car regardless of where the car is means that your knowledge about this choice cannot be applied to the problem. If this is the correct interpretation, it is refuted by the CMH.

Comment: @Nina Yes, you're right, the premise as I stated it is refuted by CMH. Let me restate the premise as follows. "If a piece of information X is generated in such a way that does not depend on the original setup, and no other piece of information is generated in such a way that depends on X and on the original setup, the probability will be the same whether X is given or not." This is no longer refuted by CMH, because (B) is generated in such a way that depends on (A) and on the original setup, so (A) does not satisfy the conditions of the premise.

Comment: @Nina On the other hand, in RMH, both (A) and (B) satisfy the conditions of the premise, so we can claim on the basis of the premise that the probability in the RMH problem is the same as the probability of the problem in which only (C) is given.

Comment: Now, though, your premise is very specific, and we have the same problem we had earlier: if we assume something and come up with the right answer, does this mean the thing we assumed is accurate?

Comment: @Nina Of course not. The premise as stated is intuitively obvious to me. That doesn't mean it's intuitively obvious to everyone, and, of course, if it's not intuitively obvious to you, you won't find the argument very convincing. I think the premise can be defended on mathematical grounds along the lines of the beginning of stewbasic's answer, but that requires knowledge of Bayes' Theorem, which is a more advanced probability concept than is needed to just chart out the possibilities in RMH and get 50/50.

Comment: @Nina So, if you don't accept that premise as obvious, I'd say: Yes, there is another argument for 50/50 in RMH which is qualitatively different from charting out the possibilities. No, it's not simpler, since it relies on a premise which has to be defended by more advanced probability concepts.

Comment: I think the part of the premise I don’t understand is “and no other piece of info is generated based on X and the original setup” because I don’t see how this means it doesn’t apply to CMH. Monty will always intentionally choose a goat door. This information is not based on X or the original setup. It’s stated in the problem. When you choose your door, you now know X. From this point on, you gain no knowledge about the benefits of switching. Not when Monty chooses the door and not when he opens it. It’s still gonna be 2/3 if you switch, 1/3 if you don’t.

Comment: @Nina The way I set up the problem, (B) was "Monty chooses door 3," not "Monty chooses a goat door." You're setting up the problem differently, which lends itself to different analysis

Comment: @ Y. Forman Then you're not describing the CMH. The classic presentation of the problem says the Monty opens door #3, yes. But this is a hypothetical that makes discussing the problem easier. This is not what you're doing. You're saying that Monty will always open door #3 because it is stated in the problem and that he will always reveal a goat. This situation disregards certain outcomes. For example, if Monty always chooses door #3, then we are not considering scenarios where you chose door #3! There's a difference between "say he opens #3" and "he always opens #3."

Comment: @Nina Since the numbering is just  a convention, the problem I'm describing (where you guess Door 1 and Monty opens Door 3) is equivalent to CMH by symmetry.  I should have been more explicit about this earlier. But we can consider this problem -- call it CMH(1,3) -- and since CMH(1,3) gives the same answer as CMH(1,2) and CMH(3,2) etc., and CMH is just the union of all these cases, the answer for CMH will be the same.

Comment: @Nina So, in 1/3 of cases where you guess 1 and Monty chooses 3, the car is where you guessed; and in 1/3 of cases where you guess 1 and Monty chooses 2, the car is where you guessed; etc.; therefore in 1/3 of all CMH cases the car is where you guessed.  I'm using numbering in RMH similarly.

Comment: You've misunderstood. I agree with all of what you've just said. But in a previous comment you claimed that the way you set up the problem, "(B) was "Monty chooses door 3."" This was in response to my point that after you've made your initial choice, nothing Monty can do will affect your switch/don't switch decision.  So logically, you're claiming that "Monty chooses door 3" tells us something to affect that decision. This is only correct if the choice of door 3 is not based on Monty's knowledge, but instead the parameter that he always chooses door 3. Which changes the problem.

Comment: @Nina In CMH Monty chooses based on his knowledge; it's given that he chooses door 3. That very given is a piece of information generated by Monty's knowledge of the original setup.  The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Nina The fact "Monty chooses door 3" - a choice made by Monty on the basis of his knowledge - is a fact which is generated by the setup.  Therefore it cannot be discarded -- as evidenced by the fact that in a CMH problem with only (A) and (C) given, the probability is 1/2-1/2. That's my claim.

Comment: "Monty chooses based on his knowledge" and "it's given that he chooses door 3" contradict each other. I think I see your reasoning: that Monty is given to open door 3 if you're given to pick door 1. Not true. But let's look at this. 1/3 of the time, the car is behind door 1. In this case Monty can both choose based on his knowledge and always choose door 3. (cont.)

Comment: However, 2/3 of the time, the goat is behind door 1. Now his choice of door 3 is seen in a different light. 1/2 of the time, the goat is behind door 2 and he chooses door 3 out of necessity. And 1/2 of the time, the goat is behind door 3 and he cannot both use his knowledge and pick door 3. (cont.)

Comment: Yes Monty knows the setup. This does not mean he sets up the setup. If he never puts the car behind door 3, then its a totally different problem. And he would have to do this if you want both "Monty chooses based on his knowledge" and "Monty always chooses door 3" to be true.

Comment: @Nina I'm not claiming "Monty always chooses door 3" -- I'm saying (B) restricts us to considering that subset of cases in which Monty chooses door 3. There are other cases in which Monty chooses a different door. Do you understand the distinction I'm making?

Comment: I want to thank you for your time and effort trying to explain this to me!! At this point, I'm not interested in continuing the argument. Looking at where we are vs. your original explanation... this thread strongly resembles a train derailment. I have no idea about how our current arguments pertain to my original question. If you'd like to start from the beginning and make another attempt at convincing me of your reasoning, I'll happily listen! But, of course, I have no expectation that you do that. You've already gone above and beyond! Thanks again!

Comment: @Nina Haha you're probably right... maybe I'll edit my answer / post a new answer which goes through my updated post- back-and-forth  thoughts thoroughly and carefully, maybe not. I think we can definitely conclude that even if there is a qualitatively different argument, it's certainly not "simple" if it leaves itself to this much debate! Thank you as well; I've really enjoyed the whole conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question may be most easily answered by working backwards. And also for convenience let’s say we’re dealing with car vs. empty, instead of car vs. goat.

When you’re faced with a choice between two visually identical doors, you’re inclined to think that because it’s one or the other, it’s a 50/50 proposition.

The comedian Gallagher once joked that a weatherman saying there’s a 50% chance of rain was just saying it will or it won’t rain. But of course ‘it will or it won’t’ encompasses a greater range of probabilities. An either-or description may refer to many ratios: 50:50, 60:40, 1:99, etc.

So we start by recognizing that this may not be an 50:50 situation.

If I told you that previously the car was known to have been behind one of three doors instead of two, but one of them was eliminated when a child wandered up and opened it, revealing no car to be present, that information would correctly do nothing to make either remaining door more attractive to you.

If, however, you learn that prior to the child opening the door, the contents of that room had been added to the one to the left of it, you’d realize that the room to the left was doubly likely to conceal the car.

It would have 2/3 of the contents of the three rooms; whereas, the other remaining choice would contain 1/3.

In our problem, the host produces this effect by deliberately showing you that B is empty if A holds the car, and showing you A is empty if B holds the car.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that if he shows the goat by random then it's 50/50. It shouldn't matter whether he knows or not since you're the one making the decision based on the information you have. He is revealing new information regardless.

There is initially a 1/3 chance that the door you selected is the correct one and therefore a 2/3 chance that one of the other doors is correct. After finding out that one of the other doors is incorrect, there is still a 2/3 chance that one of the other doors is correct, except now there's only one door.

Comment: Nope.  If **you believe** that Monty was being fair, then you would *have a reason* to *update* your probability for picking the car's door *after* being presented with *evidence* that Monty did not reveal the car; since the event of the evidence occurring would be *dependent* on whether or not you selected the door hiding the car.